# Error on opening qd.openrecordset

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

What is wrong in this sample ?  It breaks where indicated, even while the tbl name provided is the one of a perfectly working linked table.

```vb
Sub showLinked(tbl As String)
'tbl is the name of an existing local linked table (SQL Server)'
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qd As QueryDef
    Set db = CurrentDb

    With db.TableDefs(tbl)
        Debug.Print .Name, .SourceTableName, .Connect
        Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("")
        qd.Connect = .Connect
        qd.SQL = "select 1 xxx from " & .SourceTableName
        qd.ReturnsRecords = True
        Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset()     'breaks here: error 3146 - "ODBC--call failed"
        Debug.Print "test connection:", rs.Fields(0)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `"select 1 xxx from " & .SourceTableName` give you?  Is it a valid `SELECT` statement in SQL Server?

Comment: Yep, invalid SQL. Try with  `"select top 1 * from " & .SourceTableName`

Comment: @HansUp: it returns a recordset with 1 field named `xxx` with value 1 - works in SSMS.  
@Gustav: tried your suggestion, same error.

Comment: I tested your code in Access 2010 with a link to a table in SQL Server 2008, but have not been able to reproduce the error.  My link uses `DRIVER=SQL Server;` and `Trusted_Connection=Yes;`.  The recordset `rs` includes the single column you described, repeated for as many rows as exist in the remote table.  That recordset doesn't seem very useful, but I presume it's a simplified proxy for your real-world use case.

Comment: @HansUp: thanks...and sorry: see my own answer

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit: I was testing my function on an Access table called `Data_Archive_Transaction` and its `SourceTableName` is `Data_Archive.Transaction` (not my name, I promise).
Since `Transaction` is a reserved word, in a SELECT it must be surrounded with brackets: `Data_Archive.[Transaction]`.
I tried with another table with a more normal name and it worked fine.